# onclick not working after append dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="demo_restaurant">
<li class="school" onclick="dropdown(this)">
    <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
    </span>
     <span id="1" class="school_title item_title">ABC
    </span>
</li>
<li class="school" onclick="dropdown(this)">
    <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
    </span>
     <span id="2" class="school_title item_title">WXY
    </span>
</li>
</div>
```

I was trying to get the li id value when someone click on that li with following code:

```
  $(".demo_restaurant li span").on("click", function (argument) {
     alert($(this).attr('id'));  
  });
```

But the problem is when i added more li with append after ajax call. Then li onclick doesn't work. In that append elements can't call that click function though it's there in HTML. How can i make it work?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
  $('.demo_restaurant').on('click', 'li span', function(argument) {
     alert($(this).attr('id'));  
  });
```

Explanation:

> When elements are added to the DOM dynamically, you need
>   to tell jQuery to listen for events on the closest parent that was
>   there when your handler was bound. (Note that it would also work with any further parent, up to `document`, but it is considerably less optimal.)

Another way would be to bind the handler to your added DOM everytime you add some new content.